# HDFC payment gateway give error(TranPortal ID required)

Tags: php, payment-gateway

i am working on hdfc payment gateway, test payment worked fine with me, when working with live payment it will give following error

Transaction Status
Merchant Reference No:[TRACK_ID]    20583
Transaction PaymentID
Transaction Reference No
Transaction ID
Transaction Amount  1.00
Transaction Error   **!***ERROR!-GW00460-TranPortal ID required*****

Answer (score 0):

[HDFC Payment Gateway Integration](https://www.ipistis.com/hdfc-payment-gateway-integration/) is quite easy, just need to follow their integration kit.

It seems like 1. You have missed TID 2. you are trying from another domain which is not registered with HDFC.

If you can share code what you have that will be more helpful to give you solution but these 2-3 can be the scenario.